# Get a word from a string, change it, and put it back to the correct place

Tags: c++, string, vector, words

I am trying to receive an input, whatever it may be. Do something to the word, and then cout the word back to the user. Here is the thing, I cannot restrict the user from entering whatever they want, so I have to deal with the consequences. Before you guys start accusing me, no, its not a homework.

I have to keep the words in their respective places. So if someone writes

```
> "  he*llo !w3rld  ."
```

I have to keep the metacharacters in their places.

So lets say the change was just to scramble. It has to output

```
> "  eh*olo !w3ldr  ."
```

What I want to do with the word once I retrieve it is not relevant. The only problem I'm having is actually recognizing the word, doing something to it and returning it.

To make you understand better here is my below code

```
int main(){

string str;
cout<<"Enter a string: ";
getline(cin, str);
cout<<endl;
str= str + " ";


int wordFirstLetter = 0;
int currentWordLen = 0;
int p=0;
while((unsigned)p <str.length())
{
    if (isalpha(str[p])) // if letter
 { 
    str[p] = tolower(str[p]);
    currentWordLen++;
 }

  else if(!isalpha(str[p])) { //if no letter    

cout <<change(str.substr(wordFirstLetter,currentWordLen)) + " ";
wordFirstLetter = p+1;
//currentWordLen++;

currentWordLen = 0;

}
p++;

//cout<<wordFirstLetter<<" "<<currentWordLen<<endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

As you can see here I am running a a function called change on the substring every time the space in the array of the string is not a letter. But this fails miserably, because if the sentence starts with a space or has multiple spaces then the program crashes.

I have been looking around and thinking a lot about this. There needs to be two states, where I find a letter and where I don't. If I find something before I even hit one letter I can print it out.

I need to preserve that letter in some other space while I keep looking inside the sentence. When I hit something that is not a letter I need to change the word and print it along with whatever I hit and then reset the space and keep going. I just can't get around my head the functional way of doing this.

There is no need to use regular expressions, I feel it would be overkill. So please do not come to me with modern regex libraries and try to teach them to me and since I am not writing in pearl where regex is integrated I have no use for them. And there is no need to use Finite state machines.

I feel like this is such an easy thing but I just can't hit the spot.

In another thread someone suggested the below code to find words

```
std::vector<std::string> &split(const std::string &s, char delim, std::vector<std::string> &elems) {
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    std::string item;
    while (std::getline(ss, item, delim)) {
        elems.push_back(item);
    }
    return elems;
}


std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string &s, char delim) {
    std::vector<std::string> elems;
    split(s, delim, elems);
    return elems;
}
```

It got a lot of positive reviews but I don't know how to implement that and work with what I want.

I will edit as you guys ask me questions. Thanks

Comment: -1, oh man, please correctly indent your first code, at the moment it looks awful.

Comment: It crashes? Space is not a character, a letter nor a number, you can check what the user input is, to make sure it is any character or any letter or any number. You might be restricted to C or Compilers coding and provision such as "No Spaces".

Comment: "The only problem I'm having is " and then you go on and list **all** the subtasks you need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like that :

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<std::string> &split(const std::string &s, char delim, std::vector<std::string> &elems) {  
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    std::string item;
    while (std::getline(ss, item, delim)) {
        if ( item.lenght() > 0) {   // This checks if the string is not empty, to filter consecutive white space.
            elems.push_back(item);
        }
    }
    return elems;
}

std::string doSomething(const std::string original) {
    // do whatever you want with original which is a word.
    return modified; // where modified is std::string
}

int main() {
    std::string input;
    std::vector<string> listOfWords;

    std::cout << "Input your phrase :" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> input;

    split(input, " ", &listOfWords);

    for(int i = 0; i < listOfWords.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << "Input was : " << listOfWords[i]
                  << "now is : " << doSomething(listOfWords[i]);
    }

}
```

Comment: @Ali I'm not fishing for points, but it is general good practice on stackoverflow to accept the answer that you consider the most appropriate to your question. Here it doesn't really matter because you question is a bit too specific but still.

Comment: Felix how do i specify multiple delimiters for this code? How can i specify a delimiter as anything but a letter in the alphabet?

Comment: I actually dont know how pick your answer as the best. But then again i dont have anything to compare it to.

Comment: there is a tick that you can click on next to the arrows to vote on the answer (at the top left of the answer). I am suggesting this because if you have too many questions with no accepted answers it looks bad. I'll edit the answer to give you an idea of how to match patterns instead of characters)

Comment: If you're just woried about 2 consecutive empty spaces then you can just check that each string isn't empty before adding it to the vector. If you really need to filter everything but letters, then look at the `<regex>`hearder. This is c++11 so you need a recent compiler. You can find similar a library in boost TR1 if your compiler is too old. Regular expression can express such queries and filters very effectively. If you don't know about them, learn. this is a very VERY useful skill.

Comment: Thank you felix i have already solved this problem myself i have made a string called word and put the input string on a loop if the pointer runs into a letter it adds the letter to the word and if not it just prints it out. When the word ends it does something to the word, prints it out and then empties the word and starts all over again. This way if a person writes anything other than a letter it just prints it out which is what i wanted. Thanks for your support though. Im kinda glad i didnt have to get into regex and boost or finite machines.